# How do I deploy a public facing SharePoint 2007 Site

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, moss, wss, extranet

I am new to the SharePoint Development world and I have been given the task of making a public facing (extranet) site. I have been searching the web for a step by step and things to know, but have failed horribly!

Can anyone help me by either directing me to a post I may have overlooked or providing me a step by step guide to follow?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you find [Deployment for Office SharePoint 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx)?

Comment: No I didn't find this... wow now i feel sheepish :)

Thanks for the post!

Comment: I usually find it worthwhile to go to the source on these things, at least at first. If you don't find what you're looking for, complain to them and then look elsewhere. In general, Google isn't as invested in you making good use of SharePoint as Microsoft is.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Microsoft's [Extranet Resource Center for SharePoint Products and Technologies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb736207.aspx). This is the most comprehensive site I've found that should contain everything you're looking for.